# How to set a monitoring on customized Event log

Tags: windows, events, powershell, batch-file, powershell-1.0

Actually I want to achieve following 3 things in my Master.bat file:

```
1.  Collect and redirect all the entries of ‘Application’ event log to an output file.
2.  Search for a specific error message “The system cannot find the file specified” in Application event log and append the whole error message line to a log file.
3.  Send an Email notification to alert me about the error message found on daily basis.
```

**Master.bat**

```
wevtutil qe Application >D:\test\Applog.txt 
findstr /i /c:"The system cannot find the file specified" "D:\test\Applog.txt" > "D:\test\errorlog.txt"
PowerShell.exe -file D:\test\Mail.ps1 %1 %2
```

**Mail.ps1**

```
if (Select-String -Path D:\test\Applog.txt -pattern "The system cannot find the file specified") 
{
 function sendMail{
Write-Host "Sending Email"
$smtpServer = "smtp.domain.com"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
 $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
 $msg.From = "No-reply@domain.com"
 $msg.To.Add("sunny@domain.com ") 
 $msg.subject = "Error found in log"
 $msg.body = "please check there is a known error in Application log."
$smtp.Send($msg)
 }
sendMail
}
else
{write-host "nothing to process"}
```

The problem I am facing here is, unfortunately that Applog.txt log is left with a ton of data to look through and when I am scheduling Master.bat, I am receiving Email notifications for the Error messages which had been occurred many days before, which I don’t want. I want to receive Error message notification email only for current date of today.

Can anybody please help me out here ?

Comment: V1 - really?  That seven years old and 3 revs behind the current V4. If you can move to V3, you could use Get-WinEvent and do everything in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make this a lot simpler by moving to V3 and using `Get-WinEvent` to do the whole task in a PowerShell script e.g.:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
$pattern = 'The system cannot find the file specified'
$events = Get-WinEvent -LogName Application | 
              Where {$_.TimeCreated -gt $date -and $_.Message -match $pattern} | 
              Out-String -Width 110
if ($events) {
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.domain.com -From No-reply@bt.com -To sunny@domain.com -Subject 'Error found in log' -Body $events
}
```

Comment: @Keith..I can have another system to run this script where V2.0 is installed but unfortunately I am not allowed to upgrade to v3.0. Will above solution work on V2.0 ? Meanwhile I am checking from my side...

Comment: I think you will need to use Get-EventLog on V2.

Comment: …I checked the script on V2.0 system and the good thing is Get-WinEvent & Get-EventLog both are working perfectly giving the same result....:) but my 2nd point objective is yet to achieve, redirection of the error message to a separate log file, where I should add redirection above..?

Comment: The script above mails the error messages in the body of the message. To put them in a fail do this: $events > d:\test\errorlog.txt

Comment: Thanks Keith..now everything is working like a charm in a single program…thanks for your help..:)

Comment: FYI Sunny (Keith I assume you already know this!), -FilterHashTable or -FilterXPath can make searching much faster (when compared to piping to Where-Object), but they're a bit trickier to construct.

Comment: @Rob..yes i agree , its a little slow..can you please elaborate in details how to construct -FilterHashTable or -FilterXPath in above case ?

Comment: The help topic on Get-WinEvent shows some examples of how to use these parameters.  Execute: man get-winevent -full

Comment: Yes..got the way how to use -FilterHashTable or -FilterXPath to speed up the search....thanks again...:)